# code collab and git -> Add Changes does not show changed files

Tags: git, code-collaborator

We are using git for our local repository and Code Collab as our code review tool. Everything seems to work, but when I click Add Changes... no files are ever picked up as changed. I always have to use Add Git Diffs... instead.

We are running v6.0.6018

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Add Changes' adds what would be committed when you run `git commit`, and it sounds like you're a `git commit -a` user.

You should check out 7.0! There is an option (named cryptically 'git-skip-index') that when set presumes that you're going to commit with `-a`. There is also a new 'Add Unpushed Commits' feature that might convince you to review committed changes instead.